# Give access to other device in the network

Tags: networking, xampp, wifi, ojs

I am trying to build a website using Open Journal Systems (OJS).

XAMMP and OJS are already installed in the PC. Now I need other people (decision makers) to see it in the front end using their device (another PC, mobile phone). How can I configure this? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried searching here?  https://docs.pkp.sfu.ca/

Answer (score 0):

You use the tools:ngrok

https://ngrok.com/

You can proxy your localhost on the console by: ./ngrok http 80

then you will get a external domain your user can access it.